# Add a field in div tag from different page

Tags: javascript, html

Is there any way to add a field to a div tag from different part of a section for example.

I Have

```
<div id="autoUpdate" class="autoUpdate" style="margin-left: 100px; display: none;" >
        <table>
              <tr>
                    <td><bean:message key="password.label" /></td>
                    <td><html:password property="password" maxlength="100" /></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                    <td><bean:message key="re-type.password.label" /></td>
                    <td><html:password property="password" maxlength="100" /></td>
             </tr>

        </table>
</div>
```

now i want to add some field in this div on the click of a buttton in next div tag from same html file.

Answer (score 1):

HTML :

```
<div id="autoUpdate" class="autoUpdate" style="margin-left: 100px; display: none;" >
        <table>
              <tr>
                    <td><bean:message key="password.label" /></td>
                    <td><html:password property="password" maxlength="100" /></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                    <td><bean:message key="re-type.password.label" /></td>
                    <td><html:password property="password" maxlength="100" /></td>
             </tr>

        </table>
</div>
<div onClick="addField('autoUpdate')">Add Field</div>
```

Javascript

```
function addField(field_id){
  var div = document.getElementById(field_id);
  div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + 'More content';
}
```